# excel function, filter unique values on a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm having problem producing a certain result your formula via excel.

this is the sample range

[image: sample range]

then I want to get and show the unique values vertically

[image: result sample]

please help me find the best formula for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TOCOL and UNIQUE:

```
=UNIQUE(TOCOL(A1:D6))
```